# Azure DevOps Server deployment groups and tags

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2020

I'm not sure if I've stumbled across a bug or whether I am simply misinformed about how deployment groups / tags work in Azure DevOps Server 2020.

I've created a new release pipeline and configured the VSTS agent across all our servers. Each server has been configured with a tag depending on its use e.g. ServerA = WebServer1, ServerB = WebServer2.

When I add a deployment group phase to my release definition, select the deployment group and then enter the required tags i.e. WebServer1 and WebServer2, I see the message below:

No Machine Targets in WebServer deployment group

As soon as I remove the secondary tag, then it allows me to deploy to WebServer1.

Is this expected, as I am trying to deploy my release to multiple servers in my WebServer deployment group and don't want to create another environment just to deploy to WebServer2.

Comment: Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful.
If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for [marking it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which will also help others in the community.

Comment: Thank you kindly! Yes this has certainly pointed us in the right direction. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently when you use the Required tags to filter the Deployment groups targets in a job in Release, the target needs to match all Required tags, then the target could be used in deploy.

Thanks for taking time to share your suggestion. Here is an existing suggestion ticket with the same requirement in Developer Community. You can vote and track [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Deployment-Group-targets-Required-tags-i/837522?space=21&sort=relevance&q=deployment%20group%20required%20tags).